Conventions for picking variables to edit (and then changing their values) in complex editors?
I am a software developer and basically only use the browser and a text editor and pretty much no other apps (well, the terminal, google calendar, email, slack, etc., but pretty much focus on the text editor).
I don't really use complex editors like Figma, Photoshop, Sketch (graphics), Audacity, Protools (audio), After Effects, Final Cut Pro (video/animation), Maya, Blender (3D), etc.. So I don't know what is a good workflow for using the keyboard to navigate and sculpt or change variable values, and am looking for conventions or best-practices when it comes to keyboard shortcuts, in a particular regard.
For my particular situation, I am thinking of making tools which edit 2 to 20 properties let's say, which can be simple x/y values, colors, widths/heights, select boxes with many options, toggle switches, etc.. Basically:

Integer inputs
Float inputs
Range inputs
Switch/checkbox/toggle inputs
Select inputs
Autocomplete inputs
Simple text inputs
Text editor (like a code editor) inputs

Trying to keep it somewhat simple and just have these basic data types.
You are editing these values to preview something (like build a CSS box-shadow) or make a final thing happen (like create a file export).
What are some resources I can look into, or ways I can approach building the keyboard into the workflow for such an editing experience?
I am imagining Photoshop (with my limited usage of it in the past). I don't know if this is how it works, but go with me for a moment:

You press CMD+SHIFT+P to enter "command mode"
You press "x" to start editing the "x" position variable.
You then press a number, or can hold CMD and drag the mouse up or down to change its value.

Or this:

You press A then S to enter command mode
You press w then h to bind width / height to the editing mode
You type a number again and it press enter to set the width and height.

Main questions:

Are there any examples of such things out in the wild I should look carefully at?
What are the conventions for the different modes you can enter into to change what pressing a key means (command mode, edit mode, etc.)?
How can you quickly get good at jumping around properties with the keyboard and changing their values?

For my particular case, I don't expect to create a product as powerful as Figma or Maya, which needs highly configurable keyboard shortcuts. Instead, I would like to have a simple set of keyboards for editing form values on different simple editors, nothing which is customizable.

I assume that you are talking about keyboard shortcuts as action accelerators, not about basic accessibility related to keyboard navigation.
In this case, there are a few things to consider:

First of all, keyboard shortcuts should be just shortcuts, not the only way of interacting with your app. You should first design the app, test it with your users and then decide whether adding shortcuts is actually useful.

Second, you need to know what other tools and platforms are your users comfortable with, and what shortcuts they have. Your users will most likely expect similar shortcuts.

As far as I know, there is no convention when it comes to shortcuts. Each tool chooses its own custom keyboard keys for its relevant features. Your shortcuts must make sense in the context of your whole app.

Allowing users to customize their shortcuts is by far the best solution. It's impossible to account for all possible combinations between your app and all other apps that someone might use in parallel. You can create some good defaults, but it's better to also have the option to override them.

When working with many tools, some users avoid shortcuts and prefer the basic UI interaction. Remembering shortcuts requires cognitive effort and it's distracting from actually accomplishing the task. It's important to have tooltips or other UI helpers for showing available shortcuts, and not rely on memorization.

When it comes to editing modes, it's very important to clearly display which mode is the active one. Also, having more than one active mode can cause significant cognitive struggle for users, so it's better to limit your functionality to just one active mode at a time.



Overall, I recommend designing your app in such a way that it can initially be used without any shortcuts. Then you can observe which actions are repeated the most by your power users and create shortcuts for them (ideally also customizable). Keep in mind that if a tool is not accomplishing its task, there is no point in making it fast.
